# Create zip aggregation from other zips with perl

Tags: perl, zip

I'm trying to create a zip file using perl's Archive::Zip module. I have a number of already created zip files where each one contains one single csv file. I want, if possible without extracting the files, to create ONE big zip file that will contain all the individual csv files.
For example, I have:
2010-01.zip
2010-02.zip
2010-03.zip
   .
   .
2010-12.zip

And I want to create one 2010.zip that will contain 12 csv files (2010-01.csv, 2010-02.csv...2010-12.csv).

The code I have up to now is:

```
my $aggzip = Archive::Zip->new();

# get all zip files for this year
my @files = <$path*$year*.zip>; 

foreach my $file (@files) {
    my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($file); 
    my @members = $zip->members();

    my $filename = %{$members[0]}->{'fileName'};

    $aggzip->addFile( $level2Path.$filename, $filename);
 } 

if ( $aggzip->writeToFileNamed($year.".zip") != AZ_OK ) {
   die 'write error';
}
```

This does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: No error messages displayed? $level2Path isn't define in your code here. Does it exist? Does it have a value? Add use strict; use warnings; Add debugging print statements to check that variables contain what you think they do.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
my $filename = $members[0]->fileName();
```